# How do I convert an image to 5 grades of gray in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to do some shading exercises and I have a 5 values scale from white to black with 3 shades of gray.

How can I convert a picture to have only 5 colors in photoshop?

I know how to convert it to gray scale but I don't know how to take it further to only 5 colors.

Thanks

Comment: Many ways to do this, One way is to do a indexedcolr, another one is curves, a third one is gradient map save for web etc etc. What effect are you looking to achieve

Comment: Are you quite sure you mean five? You don’t mean perhaps… **fifty** shades of grey?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many methods including using *Image > Adjustments > Posterize*, or alternatively *Filters > Artistic > Cutout* - then you could tweak it with a levels or curves adjustment layer to make the lightest colour white, and the darkest black.

For example:

[image]

Another method in which you can control all the colours exactly is to convert a greyscale image to Indexed color mode.  Then simply create a custom colour table.

For example:

[image]

Another possibility is to create a gradient, and apply it as a gradient map adjustment layer.

For example:

[image]